# Why it is called Internet

Tags: networking

Hi Today was my first computer class and our teacher told me that using internet my computer talks to other computers outside my house then if it is talking to outside computers why it is called internet why not outernet

Comment: internet means `between nets`

Answer (score 2):

This question isn't really on topic for this site as it is specifically for asking questions about the **Internet of Things** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things), not the general Internet.

But the term Internet comes from the fact that it is made up of many  **net**works that are **inter**connected

Comment: actually, no. **inter** prefix means *between two or more things* - so, internet means communication between two or more networks - you have to remember that before the internet, there were many disparate networks, the internet simply enabled communication between them